# Simulating cloud chamber tracks

Tags: python, matrix, coordinates, physics, projection

I'm trying to recreate cloud chamber tracks on python, but am really struggling with the coding as it is much more complicated than any previous python work I have done. The set up is as follows:

I have two cameras (assume stereo) capturing images of the chamber from different angles. I then need to take these two images of the chamber and transform them into a 3d image of a cube, with clickable coordinates. Does anybody have any idea how to do this? Would be especially interested in finding out how to have clickable coordinates, even on the raw images, to make reconstruction easier.

Comment: You might want to look into [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of options.  Two of these are:

easy: I think **matplotlib** would be the easiest to implement, but in the end you'll probably often want features that aren't there, as 3D plotting isn't its primary strength.  [Here's](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#simple-picking-example) an example that allows you to pick points.  A good start would be to look through the [gallery page](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and see if it has everything you want.

harder: **VTK** is a very powerful 3D plotting environment, and can easily, for example, do 2D plots embedded in 3D plots ([example](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/screenshots/heart.gif)).  VTK also has pickers for user selection of objects.  There are Python bindings and also [MayaVI](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/) which provides more interaction (in terms of sliders for setting parameters, etc).  VTK is fantastic, but much harder to learn, though it's almost certain that it will do whatever you need.